# Can I ask about standard ways to visually organize tasks/developer assignments?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

As one of my tasks of organizing a team of professionals, I have to assign tasks to them and have a general idea of which major tasks are approximately going to be tackled next by who and in what order. I am looking for a way to have a visual overview of this information - maybe similar to Kanban boards, but they do not quite match what I need.

**Is *Workplace SE* the right place to ask about this kind of standard technique for managing a team at a workplace?**

Alternatively, I have thought about asking on [User Experience SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) (because at the end of the day, what I'm going to end up with is some kind of an interactive visualization, no matter whether it is (a implementation of) a specialized UI pattern or me emulating it in Excel & Co.), but that could put the focus too much on "What's the ideal solution given your parameters?" rather than on "What's the *common* solution typical for the particular workplace situation you describe?"

Also, please note that I am not intending to make this a list question. I am not looking for all kinds of options for what I could do - I can well imagine how *I* solve this; I just want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel in such a way that I end up doing it differently from how the rest of the business world does it, thus remaining incompatible to and unknowledgeable about standard practice. Thus, if there is one widely used standard method, that is the answer, but if there is none, the answer is a simple "There is none, everyone solves this problem in their own, personal way."

Comment: It's on the edge of being a list question for me in that you're almost asking for a software recommendation so you'd have to be clear that you're looking for a generic approach. It's also close to being almost too general as this is a topic I imagine you can write entire books about. That said, it still feels on-topic and answerable, I'm just adding this here because you'll need to describe this properly to avoid those pitfalls and because you may want to temper your expectations. There are a lot of planning angles you can approach this from: capacity, assignment pipeline, prioritisation, ...

Comment: @Lilienthal: Thank you for your remarks. "you'd have to be clear that you're looking for a generic approach" - I see this is an important thing to consider when writing my question, especially given that even after re-reading my question, it seems crystal-clear to me that I am nowhere even coming close to asking for any concrete tool or software, whereas it apparently isn't to you. Thus, I must be explicit about this as my own perception of the text apparently doesn't provide a good guideline here. ...

Comment: ... "There are a lot of planning angles you can approach this from" - certainly, though my requirements are quite a bit more specific than what I outlined in my initial paragraph. I just meant to provide an impression of what my question would be about, rather than already spelling out the final question, which could make it seem like I'm erroneously asking an actual in-topic question on the meta site.

Comment: It's obvious to me, it not always is to some of the more trigger-happy people patrolling the new questions who could pick up on a poorly phrased question with a List VTC. Just giving fair warning. :) And it's generally fine to provide the full text of the question you have in mind to check if it can be improved prior to posting. There's just usually no real need to do so as long as it's clear that the question wouldn't be instantly put on hold.